# Adding JavaScript to Rails app - HTML stops rendering

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am trying to get to `Hello World` with adding D3 to a Rails app but I cannot get the ordinary HTML in my view to render. I didn't want to touch the `controller` or `application.js` file and what I did seems to work with the exception of rendering the HTML...

I have added the necessary `JavaScript` files to `app/assets/javascripts`.

I updated `config/initializers/assets.rb` to:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( d3.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( sankey.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( sankeycreate.js )
```

I updated `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>D3app</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield(:body) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, I have the `app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` coded:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'd3' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'sankey' %>
<% end %>

<h1>D3 App</h1>
<p id="chart2">

<% content_for :body do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'sankeycreate' %>
<% end %>
```

I am binding an `SVG` created by `sankeycreate.js` to the `body` tag. The SVG renders with no issues and I don't see any errors, but the `<h1>D3 App</h1>` and `<p id="chart2">` elements will not render. I cannot figure out why this would be.

Comment: What is in your `js` file? And did you see the source code in browser. Just press ctrl + U and see the source code whether your `h1` and `p` tags are there or not.

Comment: My JS file contains D3 code which works because the SVG graph binds to the body tag. I should have clarified, the h1 and p tags are not in the source when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the two content_for blocks `:body` and `:head`, but the two tags you are missing aren't in any of them. If you want to render things that are outside of the content blocks just use `yield` in your layout, so rails knows where to render this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>D3app</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= yield(:body) %>
</body>
</html>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield